# Truncating Environment variable in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm trying to truncate an environment variable in an ubuntu instance using a docker image and its failing. Below I will provide example.

```
buildNum=“$(git rev-parse HEAD)” // this command returns commit hash
build= ${buildNum:0:10} //truncates commit hash to only first 20 chars
export myvar = "${build}"
error: bad substitution ???
```

The above example works on my regular OSX terminal but when trying to run the same thing in an ubuntu instance I get bad substitution error.

Comment: Try the export without extra whitespace.  `export x = 7` vs `export x=7`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with spaces around **=** sign
Try removing them.

```
export myvar="${build}"
```